# jwplayer - Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'setup'

Tags: javascript, jquery, video, jwplayer

I am trying to use jwplayer. I have used it before; I didn't have this problem then, but now I am getting this error. It is saying the object has no method setup.

Here is my HTML code:

```
<div id="#here-will-be-the-video">Loading Video...</div>
```

Here is the JS code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    console.log($('#here-will-be-the-video'));
    jwplayer('here-will-be-the-video').setup({
        file: "http://youtu.be/QtmyQRH3DEo",
        image: "http://placehold.it/500x300",
        width: 500,
        height: 300
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be

```
<div id="here-will-be-the-video">Loading Video...</div>
```

Not

```
<div id="#here-will-be-the-video">Loading Video...</div>
```

And then

```
  jwplayer('here-will-be-the-video').setup(
```

Check this link http://jsfiddle.net/ramp/nF7Mw/

Comment: Thank you very much. Sometime I feel stupid. Sorry to bouther you guys.